# Force unloading of DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have recently ventured into xml reading/writing, and have found DOM parser extremely useful and organised. But the problem arises. I realised DOM parsers eat up memory when reading xml files. Now, I just want to ask: is there a way (directly or indirectly) to tell/force Java to unload (not sure if it really is unload) that particular xml from memory? Or, is there a way to configure DOM parsers so they unload memory of the xml...?

Comment: What dom api are you using? Are you using `org.w3c.dom` ?

Comment: Yup, "org.w3c.dom". This is (for me) by far the most "useable" API for some serious look-up and modification.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but JDOM2 and XOM are much better designed APIs for this kind of thing than DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you don't hold a reference to the DOM, directly or indirectly.  Then the memory will be eligible for garbage collection, which can happen at any time (usually you won't need to worry about it).

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I don't think you could unload a xml file from memory in DOM. If memory is a constraint, I'll suggest SAX or StAX. They are much faster and don't spend time loading the whole xml file like DOM.